# HOW TO: Spark Core Time Based Event

Tags: arduino, sparkcore

I'm quiet new to Spark Core (http://www.spark.io). How can I create a time based event on my Spark Core? For instance, if I want to digitalWrite 7,HIGH at 8:30AM every morning for 30 seconds and digitalWrite 7,LOW till next day morning 8:29AM. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways.

1. Write the code in the main loop.  Wake up every 15 second and check if the prior time was before 8:30 and the current time is 8:30 or greater. If so, go HIGH.  Same logic can be used to switch low.
2. Use a service like IFTTT.com to connect to your core and call a published function to toggle your output state.  IFTTT is really cool and had some useful integrations.

Good luck!